# css background-color not working in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, background, background-color

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. The testing I've done so far is as follows:

I've checked my code in Chrome, Opera, Edge, IE11 and UC - All working as intended or as close as possible

I took out all the bells and whistles to see if i could isolate the issue - the issue would appear to be Firefox

I've tried removing all HTML code except HTML, Head and Body

I went into my firefox settings: Options>General>Language and Appearance>Fonts and Colors>Colors..., changed the Override setting to Never and it still didn't work. Thinking that I may have tried the wrong setting, I tried all three (Never, Always and Only with high contrast themes), none of them worked

I'm truly stumped. Below is the barebones of my code. . I've tried removing EVERYTHING from the HTML and just done a CSS page. No background colors are displaying in Firefox. Why is that?

**Code**

```
html {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, section {
    background-color: #999397;
}
```

**Link to Code**

https://codepen.io/Obsidiangel/pen/KoLwey

***EDIT:*** An incredibly important piece I neglected to mention in the original post above is that the Codepen background-color **is** working correctly for me, it's when I view my html doc in firefox that the code doesn't work. Again, Can't believe I missed that in the above post, but I did try the suggestions below to clear history and cache, disable addons/extension (I actually removed them altogether), and uninstall and reinstall. I'm going to try clearing the cache again and see if that helps.

Comment: Works for me in FF 59.0.1

Comment: Ditto works in FF59. Maybe some really strange cache issue? Trying viewing in private browsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I feel like a complete and utter idiot, but i finally figured out what the issue was. After I tried all of the solutions posted above, I decided to go back to basics and tried adding the background-color directly to the body tag in the HTML document and it worked exactly as expected in my Submlime file, but still wasn't working in the CSS file.

This brought me to the conclusion that I was somehow incorrectly linking my CSS file to the HTML file. I was putting the entire file location (starting from the C:) in the `<link>` tag instead of just putting "Portfolio.css". Firefox was the only browser that disliked the full location! However, good to know that I've been doing it wrong!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when i was first starting out. I also recommend clearing your cache, because the browser will save a previous version of the site for faster load times.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works on Firefox for me. Things to try:

- Delete Browser History and Cache
- Disable Extensions
- Do a fresh install of firefox with default settings

Hope one of these things helps.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine in my Firefox. You can try and clear your cache as suggested here:

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/755808

Also, check the "Helpful Reply" of the answer, pointing to Mozilla's Knowledge Base:

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Website_colors_are_wrong
http://kb.mozillazine.org/Websites_look_wrong

If these won't work, maybe a full uninstall followed by an installation of the last Firefox version may help!